# Javascript Array of Objects restructuring

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am getting data from a relational database having joined 3 tables:

```
var btnObj2 = [
{sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 1, subsect_title:'Übersicht', btn_id: 1, btn_title: 'Inhaltsverzeichnis'},
{sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 1, subsect_title: 'Übersicht', btn_id: 2, btn_title: 'Stichwortverzeichnis'},
{sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 2, subsect_title: 'Praxisphasen', btn_id: 3, btn_title: 'Trainingserfolg'},
{sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 2, subsect_title: 'Praxisphasen', btn_id: 4, btn_title: 'Trainingsablauf'},
{sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 3, subsect_title: 'Mentor-Gespräche', btn_id: 5, btn_title: 'Lebenszeit'},
{sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 3, subsect_title: 'Mentor-Gespräche', btn_id: 6, btn_title: 'Lebensplanung'},
{sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 4, subsect_title: 'Just do it', btn_id: 7, btn_title: 'Vertrauen'},
{sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 4, subsect_title: 'Just do it', btn_id: 8, btn_title: 'Verantwortung'}
];
```

This data must be restructured so that each section contains its subsections and each sub-section contains its subsub-subsections (subsub-subsections are the buttons in the code snippet above). The data from the database is already returned in the correct order according to sections, sub-sections, subsub-sections.

The output must be as below:

```
var result = [
{
    sect_id: 1,
    sect_title: 'Navigation',
    subsect: [
        {
            subsect_id: 1,
            subsect_title: 'Übersicht',
            buttons: [
                {
                    btn_id: 1,
                    btn_title: 'Verantwortung'
                },
                {
                    btn_id: 2,
                    btn_title: 'Vertrauen'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            subsect_id: 2,
            subsect_title: 'Praxisphasen',
            buttons: [
                {
                    btn_id: 3,
                    btn_title: 'Trainingserfolg'
                },
                {
                    btn_id: 4,
                    btn_title: 'Trainingsablauf'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
sect_id: 2,
sect_title: 'Module 1',
//.....
];
```

Here is how I would do it in a PHP-way:

```
function prepareBtns(arr) {
    var sectId, subsectId = ''
    var newArr = []
    arr.forEach((item) => {
        if(sectId !== item.sect_id){
            sectId = item.sect_id
        }
        if(subsectId !== item.subsect_id){
            subsectId = item.subsect_id
        }
        //In PHP the following line does the Job
        newArr[sectId][subsectId][] = item
    })
    return newArr
}
```

This is one of my JS trials. This one resulted in empty slots:

```
function prepareBtnsXY(arr) {
var newArr = [];
arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (!newArr[item.sect_id]) {

        var objToPush = {
            sectId: item.sect_id,
            sectName: item.sect_title,
            subsect: []
        };
        newArr[item.sect_id] = objToPush;
    }

    if (!newArr[item.sect_id].subsect[item.subsect_id]) {
        var subObjToPush = {
            subsectId: item.subsect_id,
            subsectName: item.subsect_title,
            buttons: []
        };
        newArr[item.sect_id].subsect[item.subsect_id] = subObjToPush;
    }

    if (!newArr[item.sect_id].subsect[item.subsect_id].buttons[item.btn_id]) {
        var btnObjToPush = {
            btnId: item.btn_id,
            btnName: item.btn_title
        };
        newArr[item.sect_id].subsect[item.subsect_id].buttons[item.btn_id] = btnObjToPush;
    }
});

return newArr
}
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store the wanted keys in another array where the first key of each row is the key value for grouping, the following keys are the data keys for this level and the last key is for children/sub levels. The final array does not contains a children value, but a placeholder of `undefined`.

> ```
> keys = [
>   //  level key          level  properties        children
>   // ------------  ----------------------------- ----------
>     ['sect_id',    'sect_title' /* more keys */, 'subsect'],
>     ['subsect_id', 'subsect_title',              'buttons'],
>     ['btn_id',     'btn_title',                  undefined]
> ],
> ```

The algorithm iterates the data and reduces the keys by taking the actual array and searches for a same grouping key and value. If not found, it generates a new level with the given keys and pushs it to the array and return the children array for the next level.

The advantage of this approach is, it is easy to maintain by simply changing the raw data and the corresponding `keys` array, which acts as grouping rule set.

```js
var data = [{ sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 1, subsect_title: 'Übersicht', btn_id: 1, btn_title: 'Inhaltsverzeichnis' }, { sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 1, subsect_title: 'Übersicht', btn_id: 2, btn_title: 'Stichwortverzeichnis' }, { sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 2, subsect_title: 'Praxisphasen', btn_id: 3, btn_title: 'Trainingserfolg' }, { sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 2, subsect_title: 'Praxisphasen', btn_id: 4, btn_title: 'Trainingsablauf' }, { sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 3, subsect_title: 'Mentor-Gespräche', btn_id: 5, btn_title: 'Lebenszeit' }, { sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 3, subsect_title: 'Mentor-Gespräche', btn_id: 6, btn_title: 'Lebensplanung' }, { sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 4, subsect_title: 'Just do it', btn_id: 7, btn_title: 'Vertrauen' }, { sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 4, subsect_title: 'Just do it', btn_id: 8, btn_title: 'Verantwortung' }],
    keys = [['sect_id', 'sect_title', 'subsect'], ['subsect_id', 'subsect_title', 'buttons'], ['btn_id', 'btn_title', undefined]],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.reduce((a, k) => {
            var temp = a.find(p => o[k[0]] === p[k[0]]);
            if (!temp) {
                a.push(temp = Object.assign(
                    ...k.map((l, i, { length }) =>
                        l && { [l]: i + 1 === length ? [] : o[l] })
                ));
            }
            return temp[k[k.length - 1]];
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired result with something like this:

```js
let r = {}, data = [{ sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 1, subsect_title: 'Übersicht', btn_id: 1, btn_title: 'Inhaltsverzeichnis' }, { sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 1, subsect_title: 'Übersicht', btn_id: 2, btn_title: 'Stichwortverzeichnis' }, { sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 2, subsect_title: 'Praxisphasen', btn_id: 3, btn_title: 'Trainingserfolg' }, { sect_id: 1, sect_title: 'Navigation', subsect_id: 2, subsect_title: 'Praxisphasen', btn_id: 4, btn_title: 'Trainingsablauf' }, { sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 3, subsect_title: 'Mentor-Gespräche', btn_id: 5, btn_title: 'Lebenszeit' }, { sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 3, subsect_title: 'Mentor-Gespräche', btn_id: 6, btn_title: 'Lebensplanung' }, { sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 4, subsect_title: 'Just do it', btn_id: 7, btn_title: 'Vertrauen' }, { sect_id: 2, sect_title: 'Modul 1', subsect_id: 4, subsect_title: 'Just do it', btn_id: 8, btn_title: 'Verantwortung' } ];

while (data.length) {
  let {sect_id,sect_title,subsect_id,subsect_title,btn_id,btn_title} = data.pop(),
  subsect = {subsect_id, subsect_title, buttons: [{btn_id, btn_title}]}
  
  if(!r[sect_id]) 
    r[sect_id] = {sect_id, sect_title, subsect: [subsect]}
  else {
    let sub = r[sect_id].subsect.find(x => x.subsect_id == subsect_id)
    if(sub) sub.buttons.push({btn_id, btn_title})
    else r[sect_id].subsect.push(subsect)
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(r))
```

The idea is to  use `while` and `Array.pop` to keep getting elements from the aray and keep building the tree.